# Xcode no longer shows Xcode Bots / OS X Server from Local Network

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, osx-server, xcode-bots

I have a Mac Mini on my local network that runs Xcode Bots for continuous integration.

Recently, these Bots stopped appearing in the Xcode Reports Navigator where they normally are located. I can no longer see the Bots' integration logs or tell them to "Integrate Now".

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, this issue seems related to the [discoveryd clusterf***](http://furbo.org/2015/05/05/discoveryd-clusterfuck/) in Mac OS X Yosemite.

Go to `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Servers`

When the Xcode Bots were not visible, `Servers` listed only "Mac mini (2)". This was apparently different than the current name/address of the Mac Mini on the local network.

Use `Add Server...` to re-add the Mac Mini Xcode Server with its new name/address.

You'll now have 2 Mac Minis listed under `Servers`. One of them will allow you to view the Xcode Bots on your local network.

[image: Add Server to Xcode]